# Contract vertices the graph and combine attributes

Tags: r, igraph

I came across a problem.

I have the scenery following:

```
# Create a graph
g1 <- graph.full(5)
V(g1)$name <- letters[1:vcount(g1)]
V(g)
Vertex sequence:
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e"

# Contract vertex "a" and "b"
vec = c(1,1,2,3,4)
contract_1 <- contract.vertices(g1, vec, vertex.attr.comb=toString)
V(contract_1)
Vertex sequence:
[1] "a, b" "c" "d" "e"  

# Contract vertex "a, b" and "c"
vec = c(1,1,2,3)
contract_2 <- contract.vertices(contract_1, vec, vertex.attr.comb=toString)
V(contract_2)
Vertex sequence:
[1] "a, b, c" "d" "e"
```

And so on ... (contract "a, b, c" and "d", creating the vertex "a, b, c, d")

I need to differentiate the vertexs of the previous level.

Eg.:

By contracting the vertices "a, b​​" and "c", I need using a extra markup as "|" or ";". In this case, the result would be "a, b | c" or "a, b- c" or "a, b; c".

By contracting the vertices "a, b, c" and "d" the result would be "a, b, c | d" or "a, b, c; d"

I tried a few things ...

Eg.:

```
g <- contract.vertices(g, matching, 
  vertex.attr.comb=list(name=function(x) paste(toString(x,"",sep=";"))))
```

However, not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`paste` also has a `collapse` argument:

```
contract.vertices(
  contract_1, 
  c(1,1,2,3), 
  vertex.attr.comb = list( name = function(x) paste(x, collapse=";") )
)
```

You could also use nested parentheses:

```
library(igraph)
g <- list()
k <- 5
g[[1]] <- graph.full(k)
V(g[[1]])$name <- letters[1:vcount(g1)]
for(i in 2:k) { 
  g[[i]] <- contract.vertices(
    g[[i-1]],
    c(1,1,2:k)[1:(k-i+2)],
    vertex.attr.comb = list( name = function(x) 
      if( length(x) > 1 ) paste0( "(", paste0(x,collapse=","), ")" ) else x
    )
  )
}
lapply(g, V)
# [[1]]
# Vertex sequence:
# [1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e"
# [[2]]
# Vertex sequence:
# [1] "(a,b)" "c"     "d"     "e"    
# [[3]]
# Vertex sequence:
# [1] "((a,b),c)" "d"         "e"        
# [[4]]
# Vertex sequence:
# [1] "(((a,b),c),d)" "e"            
# [[5]]
# Vertex sequence:
# [1] "((((a,b),c),d),e)"
```

Comment: Perfect. It's what I need. But, a doubt: How to navigate in the result? In other words, how unzip one level. Eg.: Given `"((((a,b),c),d),e)"` get `"((a,b),c),d)"` and `"e"`. I will try to use regular expressions.

Comment: Yes, you can use s regular expression, e.g., `strsplit( gsub( "\\((.*),([^,]*)\\)", "\\1;\\2", "((((a,b),c),d),e)"), ";" )[[1]]`.